# Php Server error caused by return ?:"http"

Tags: php, http, server-error

I'm a novice php and I'm stuck on a problem I was hoping someone could offer me help with.

When I upload a .php with the following contents to my server and load it in a chrome browser there doesn't seem to be any problem.

```
<?php

 class AppInfo {
   public static function getHome () {
   return ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])."://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
 }
```

}

However when I upload a .php file containing the very similar code below (the difference is the presence of ?:"http"), chrome returns a server error (pasted below the code)

```
<?php
class AppInfo {
  public static function getHome () {
    return ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ?: "http") . "://" .    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
 }
}
```

Error:

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving "Url" It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: That's invalid syntax.  What do you think it does?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I mean, what's the output you're looking for?

Comment: That's a parse error for PHP 5.2 and earlier. The `?:` shortcut only works from 5.3 and onward.

Comment: Thanks Mario that's great to know. It turns out I'm using PHP 5.2

Answer (score 1):

You should change it to

```
return ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] : "http") . "://" .    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
```

So this would mean that if `($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` is there use it else use `http`.

Comment: This does not throw an error. Once I verify that this function is still performing it's intended task I will mark this as correct. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to use what's called the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). This operator expects the following syntax:

```
(comparison statement) ? (what to do if true) : (what to do if false)
```

The documentation states that you may omit the middle clause (the 'what to do if true' clause), only if you're using PHP 5.3 or later. In my opinion, this is bad practice. I'm not aware of any other programming languages that allow that shortcut, and it only makes reading your code that much more difficult (especially if you're reading it a year or more after you wrote it). It's best to write code that is (where possible) backwards compatible; it will be that much more portable as a result.

**Update:** I read a little about the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) on Wikipedia, and a few other languages do have shortcuts like this (a GNU extension for C exists, for example). I still think using the shortcut is bad; the case where statement evaluation results in side effects springs to mind.

Comment: `I'm not aware of any other programming languages that allow that shortcut` - actually Javascript does, but the syntax is different as it uses the `||` OR operator, so I suppose it is not exactly the same. E.g. `var someVar = someOtherVar || 6;` gives `someVar` the value of `someOtherVar` if it evaluates to true, and `6` if not.

Comment: @DaveRandom Logical OR is a very different operator than ternary compare. JavaScript supports the ternary operator, but both condition clauses are required (you cannot use the shortcut mentioned in the original poster's question).